# Spark.read 1M small json files timeout (Databricks)

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I need to spark.read 1M or even 500k json files in databricks but its timing out as its calling the underlying dbfs api in order to list files. Is there a way to work around this? I cant find anything online.

Error:

```
GET https://datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/volume?resource=filesystem&amp;maxResults=5000&amp;directory=Mydir&amp;continuation=MTMwNDkxNjgwNDY4OTYxOTYyNTcgMTMyMTQwLTAyNTE4MzY0MjE5MDg0MzI5NTUwLmpzb24%3D&amp;timeout=90&amp;recursive=false

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3818584394335692> in <module>()
----> 1 run()

<command-3818584394335686> in run()
     19       # Read raw jsons if has files and folders
     20       
---> 21       df = spark.read.option('multiLine', True).json(raw_folder_path + '/' + sub_folder_name + '/*')
     22 
     23         head = df.head(1)  # Low-cost check

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in json(self, path, schema, primitivesAsString, prefersDecimal, allowComments, allowUnquotedFieldNames, allowSingleQuotes, allowNumericLeadingZero, allowBackslashEscapingAnyCharacter, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, dateFormat, timestampFormat, multiLine, allowUnquotedControlChars, lineSep, samplingRatio, dropFieldIfAllNull, encoding)
    272             path = [path]
    273         if type(path) == list:
--> 274             return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    275         elif isinstance(path, RDD):
    276             def func(iterator):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1312.json.
: GET https://datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/volume?resource=filesystem&amp;maxResults=5000&amp;directory=Mydir&amp;continuation=MTMwNDkxNjgwNDY4OTYxOTYyNTcgMTMyMTQwLTAyNTE4MzY0MjE5MDg0MzI5NTUwLmpzb24%3D&amp;timeout=90&amp;recursive=false
StatusCode=500
StatusDescription=Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.
ErrorCode=InternalError
ErrorMessage=Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.
RequestId:7c187fcb-e01f-005b-7188-78dfed000000
Time:2019-10-01T18:48:40.9996759Z
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:134)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.listPath(AbfsClient.java:180)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.listStatus(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:517)
    at shaded.databricks.v20180920_b33d810.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.listStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:326)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFSV2$$anonfun$listStatus$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:86)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFSV2$$anonfun$listStatus$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:83)
    at com.databricks.s3a.S3AExeceptionUtils$.convertAWSExceptionToJavaIOException(DatabricksStreamUtils.scala:107)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFSV2$$anonfun$listStatus$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:83)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFSV2$$anonfun$listStatus$1.apply(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:83)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$recordOperation$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:359)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:230)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionContext(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:415)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:268)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.withAttributionTags(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:415)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:345)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystemV2.recordOperation(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:415)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DBFSV2.listStatus(DatabricksFileSystemV2.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.DatabricksFileSystem.listStatus(DatabricksFileSystem.scala:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.listStatus(Globber.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1657)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anonfun$globPath$1.apply(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anonfun$globPath$1.apply(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:256)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:345)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:331)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.globPath(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.globPathIfNecessary(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:600)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:595)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:467)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My cluster can scale up to 500gb of RAM memory and 128 cores. 
I checked the cluster drivers logs and I could not find any other infos.
I don't think the spark configuration settings would help since they don't affect the dbfs api.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if the service principal you are using for Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 is not granted the appropriate role assignment.

Make sure that your user account has the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role assigned to it.

When I use Databricks Runtime 4.2, 4.3, or 5.0, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 fails to list a directory that has lots of files.

With these runtimes, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 has a known issue that causes it to fail to list a directory that has more than 5000 files or sub-directories.

**Reference:** [Azure Data Lake Gen2 Known issues](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2.html) and [Tutorial: Access Data Lake Storage Gen2 data with Azure Databricks using Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-use-databricks-spark).

Hope this helps.